# How to make images optimized for UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, image, optimization, uiimage

I have a `ScrollView` with multiple `UIImageView`s in it which load `.jpg` images. It runs pretty influently when loading images.

How can I optimize the images to make iOS load them faster? Use which tool? In which specific format and setting? Thank you.

Comment: First of all, use PNG instead.  That will get you a really quick and easy bonus.

Comment: @borrrden png files are much more bigger in size.

Comment: That's the price you have to pay for fast loading times.  Although, PNG-8 is pretty lightweight if you don't need a lot of color depth.  JPG is a relic of the 1990s.  PNG files are highly optimized during your build:  http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.jp/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html

Comment: @BenLu ios is optimized to handle pngs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have them as png and pre load them with the "imageNamed" method. This method WILL cache them which makes loading fast. but it also knows how to handle memory which means it will unload them if you are runing low on memory.

Alternatively, depending on the size you can create the thumbnail version of these images for display. This is how the imagepicker manages to display A TON of images very fluently.

Read this question/answer: [How can I load images into the iphone system cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207847/how-can-i-load-images-into-the-iphone-system-cache)

Comment: I downloaded the images asynchronously using `ASIHTTPRequest` and stored them in `NSData`, so I have to use `initWithContentsOfFile:`. Any approach still to cache them?

Comment: initwithcontetsoffile does cache them: This method loads the image data into memory and marks it as purgeable. If the data is purged and needs to be reloaded, the image object loads that data again from the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

use cached images. first time it may take time but after that it will be faster.